# Create byte[] in Jython

Tags: arrays, jython

I am developing with Jython and I need to use a Java method that requires a `byte[]` as a parameter.

I tried:

```
def randomBytesArray(length):
    data = []
    for _ in xrange(length):
        data.append(chr(random.getrandbits(8)))
    methodThatNeedsBytesArrays(data)
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: methodThatNeedsBytesArrays(): 1st arg can't be coerced to byte[]
```

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you need to pass a byte array to a function so that the function will fill the byte array with a result.  In that case, sending a Python string won't work because Python strings are immutable.  Instead, create a Java byte array with the [jarray module](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/jarray.html):

```
import jarray
bytes = jarray.zeros(100, "b")
length = zlibDeflater.deflate(bytes)
...
```